# When are beans created and are same beans used in different beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The question is a little bit confusing, but there are two parts only :

1. In a Spring web application, when are the beans configured in its
   XML files instantiated ?
2. When we use `ref` to configure a bean
   as a property of the "outer" bean, is a new bean "object" created?
   or it uses the already present bean object (maybe created by some
   other `ref` or `<bean>`) ?

Comment: spring beans are singletons. it will always be the same instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ans 1 : In `applicationContext.xml`(IoC Container), the beans are configured and instantiated at the same time and they are singleton in nature.

Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Spring Application Context File -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Custom bean -->  
    <bean id="demo" class="com.example.Demo" />
</beans>
```

Ans 2 : When you use `ref`, it uses the already present bean configured in the `applicationContext.xml`.

Example :

```
<bean id="demo" class="com.example.Demo" />

<bean id="demo_2" class="com.example.Demo_2" >
    <property name="demo" ref="demo">
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, second point answers it I suppose, but forgive me for my confusing grammar, but I was asking when, in the life time of the spring-web application in the server, the beans created.

Comment: @JaideepSagar    All beans are loaded/created from `applicationContext.xml` when the application starts (at very first time).